# KNN was used for filling null in model development, how to fill null in model serving

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, imputation

There were 500+ features and a respond, most of the features have missing values. So I used KNN to fill null before feature selection. Finall, 30 out of them were chosen and a xgboost model was build.

For future prediction on new data with the model, how to fill null for the 30 features in new data?